# Force SWF (Flash file) to load LAST after rest of webpage

Tags: html, css, flash, web, dreamweaver

I have a rather complex flash clip that ends up bogging down the loading of the rest of my webpage.

Can I force the flash to wait to load until the rest of the site loads?

Comment: you may use swf object js

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind to have javascript you may use something like SFWObject 2 library, here is documentation page http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation there is different methods for using it, so you just need pick up which is more appropriate in your case. Main idea you may trigger swf player initialization with javascript, so you could control time when this happen, and so using it just do that after `onload` event triggering. But assume problem cold be more complicated than just delaying your clip, so try to test it on different computers and browsers.

Comment: I've actually been specifically trying to avoid javascript as much as possible, so if you had any other suggestions I would welcome them. Otherwise, I'm going to look into SFWObject 2 a little more, Thank you!

Comment: assume for pure no js solution you may search for/create own flash player which will do clip upload with delay, or probably use some action script's core methods for defining page load, but remember that Adobe has ended support for flash plugin, and deprecated usage of it in favor of html5